# Control not hitting the set property wpf mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a double type property which is binded with textbox(WPF). When I lost the focus with empty textbox the control is not hitting the set property. 
If I give a valid input like 10.2 then it's hitting the set property of viewmodel. Is there any solution please to hit the control over set property, even though there is invalid data?

Settings.xaml

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,0,0,10" Height="20">
                    <TextBlock Text="Minimum Peak Ratio:" Width="145"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding SkylineMinPeakRatio,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource InputStyle}">
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <Behaviors:TextBoxInputBehavior InputMode="DecimalInput"/>
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </TextBox>
                    <Button x:Name="MinPeakRatioError" Margin="5,0,0,0" Visibility="{Binding MinPeakRatioInfoVisibility,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <Image Source="..\Images\ErrorInfo.jpg"></Image>
                        <Button.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding MinPeakRatioErrMsg}"></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MinPeakRatioErrMsgDescription}"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ToolTip>
                        </Button.ToolTip>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
```

SettingsViewModel.cs

```cs
private double skylineMinPeakRatio

   public double SkylineMinPeakRatio
        {
            get
            {
                return skylineMinPeakRatio;
            }
            set
            {
                skylineMinPeakRatio=value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SkylineMinPeakRatio");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please, share your code

Comment: "*... set property, even though there is a invalid data*" - that is a contradiction in itself.

Comment: consider using `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SkylineMinPeakRatio));` as it is easier to handle when renaming properties.

Answer (score 1):

You have some ways to handle this problem (btw you get a cast exception in wpf and thats why your property setter is not hit).

1. In a perfect mvvm world you can make all your properties of type **string** and your bindings will work and you can easily do Error Validation too. The drawback of this - you now has to convert your properties to the right Type as far as your value is going to the model.
2. in your special case you could use **Nullable Double**. but if someone put some letters in your TextBox you have the same problem again. Your Setter will not hit. You can handle this with a behavior or numeric TextBox.